# React Typescript: useRef to listen outside touch event doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, render, lifecycle, use-ref

I have a component (navBar) that has two instances: Default and Responsive. Its shape on the screen is being defined by the style (sass), properly regulated by
[handleClick function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzYyy.png)

I decided to put a listener on the body element, and if there is tapping outside Menu, the function would manually take 'active' className out of Menu classList.

```
function useOutsideListener(ref: React.MutableRefObject<null | HTMLDivElement>) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleClickOutside(event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target as Element)) {
        activeMenu.forEach((itens) => {
          itens.classList.remove(styles['active']);
        });
      };
    };
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}
```

The wrapper is properly attached to the ref attribute, and the logic works as it should, but only after saving the file in vsCode and vite 're-rendering' the component. I know it's related to useRef, but I don't know a way to solve the problem.

```
function renderNavBar() {
  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useOutsideListener(wrapperRef);

  return (
    <div className={styles.navBar} ref={wrapperRef}>
      <button className={styles.menu} onClick={ handleClick } data-menu>MENU</button>
      <nav className={styles.navContainer} data-menu>
        <ul className={styles.navList}>
          <Link to="/exp">Experiência</Link>
          <Link to="/formacao">Formação</Link>
          <Link to="/projects">Projetos</Link>
          <Link to="/contact">Contato</Link>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove your dependency array in the useEffect ?

Comment: I tried to do that, I also tried to be specific in the dependency, and both failed

Comment: I think your problem might be linked to the fact that you're directly manipulating the dom, you should probably keep your styles in a state that you will change

Comment: I totally agree with you, it's a learning experience for future projects. Keep the DOM separate from it all

Answer (score 1):

I was probably using tools I know little about the wrong way. I ended up discovering the useCallback and monitoring the ref property more accurately. The final functional result looks like this:

```
    const useOutsideListener = (): [
  RefObject<HTMLDivElement>,
  (node: HTMLDivElement) => void
  ] => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const setRef = useCallback((node: HTMLDivElement) => {
    ref.current = node;
  }, [ref.current]);

  return [ref, setRef]
}
```

Using useEffect, I monitored the ref object state changes, and for a simple check, removed the style class.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(ref.current?.attributes[1].value === 'true') {
      
      document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function handleOutside(event) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const menuButton = (event.target as HTMLElement).parentElement;
          if(menuButton !== ref.current) {
            ref.current?.querySelector('nav')?.classList.remove(styles['active']);
            document.body.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleOutside);
        }}, 75);
      });
    };
    
  }, [ref.current?.attributes[1].value]);
```